# How to add System.Windows dll to Visual Studio 2010 express?

Tags: c#, .net, multimedia

I am developing a small application using *C#* and *VS2010* as *IDE* with *.NET Framework 4*.

I want to use `CaptureSource` class in order to capture video from laptop's webcam.
For that i need to add a namespace `System.Windows.DependencyObject`.

How can I add this? In the *Solution Explorer*, if I right clicked on *Referenced*, then *.NET* tab, I wont be able to see `System.Windows`. Please see the attached file the same.

Please anyone help me in adding this *System.Windows dll*.

Thanks in Advance
Sri

Answer (score 3):

According to this [MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx) the class is in the WindowsBase.dll file.

```
Namespace:  System.Windows
Assembly:  WindowsBase (in WindowsBase.dll)
```

DependencyObject is a class you cannot add it as a namespace.  The closest thing you can do is add the namespace it is located in:

```
using System.Windows;
```

Comment: hi magnifico, thanks for your quick response. i tried to locate WindowsBase.dll but failed. Do you have any idea?

Comment: hi magnifico, i could find out the windowsBase.dll, even after adding that dll into the "references" i'm not able to use System.Windows.DependencyObject namespace. Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can browse dll in your local system to add reference.
If you can not get any file with the name System.Windows.dll then you can download dll from following link and then add reference of that downloaded dll.
[click here to download dll](http://www.dllme.com/dll/download/11556/System.Windows.dll)

Answer (score 0):

Can't speak for VS2010, but a few years have passed and I just had this issue in VS2013.

In Visual Studio 2013, I did "Add Reference", and found "WindowsBase" near the bottom of Assemblies/Framework. I added that, and was able to add `using System.Windows` to files in the project. "Resolve" appeared on the context menu for `DependencyObject`, `DependencyProperty`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need to add the System.Windows reference. 
If you look at this site: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyobject?view=netframework-4.7.1
then you'll see that the assembly (dll) you actually need is one called WindowBase. 
This should be found by right-clickling "References" in your project, select "Add References" and then in the "Framework" tab select WindowsBase in the bottom of the list.

If you do this your IDE will automatically include the System.Windows namespace when you resolve (right-click on the DepedencyObject) and press "DepdendecnyObject - using system.windows".

I reproduced your situation and this worked fine for me.

Best Regards, 
Adam