# GalaSoft.MvvmLight.WP71 Compilation error , require to add reference to System.Windows for the RelayCommand

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, mvvm

I am using V3 of the MVVM Light Toolkit in VS2010 and target .NET FW of 4.0
As part of the MVVM Light toolkit usage I am using the RelayCommand class which implements the ICommand interface. 
I am also referencing the Presentation.Core assembly for the ICommand interface. 
Somehow at compilation I am getting the following error which not occur at previous versions of MVVM Light...

**The type 'System.Windows.Input.ICommand' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.**

Now, I cannot find any System.Windows assembly and why it doesn't use the 'System.Windows.Input.ICommand' type from the PresentationCore assembly...

What's wrong here ?

This is the View code

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WP71"
        Height="300" Width="300" ResizeMode="NoResize"
        WindowStyle="None" Background="Transparent" AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:Window1ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CloseWndButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"
                             Stroke="Transparent"/>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Border BorderBrush="BlanchedAlmond" BorderThickness="6" CornerRadius="8" Background="BlanchedAlmond">
        <Grid Background="BlanchedAlmond">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="25"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Style="{StaticResource CloseWndButton}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3" Content="X" Command="{Binding CloseWindowCommand}" FontSize="14" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Foreground="#FFBE3636"></Button>

        </Grid>

    </Border>
</Window>
```

This is the ViewModel

```
public class Window1ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 
        protected static Window1ViewModel viewModelInstance = null;
        public RelayCommand CloseWindowCommand { get; set; }          

        public Window1ViewModel()
        {
            CloseWindowCommand = new RelayCommand(CloseWindow);
        }

        public static Window1ViewModel Instance
        {
            get
            {
                lock (typeof(Window1ViewModel))
                {
                    if (viewModelInstance == null)
                    {
                        viewModelInstance = new Window1ViewModel();
                    }
                }
                return viewModelInstance;
            }
        }

        protected void CloseWindow()
        {
            //Messenger.Default.Send<ScaleAreaWindowClosedMessage>(new ScaleAreaWindowClosedMessage());
        }

        event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
        {
            add { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
            remove { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: there should be System.Windows have you checked in Extensions ?

Comment: No, when I am doing Add References I cannot find it. but why it needed ? I mean the ICommand defined at PresentationCore...

Comment: you need it for System.Windows.Input , that's where ICommand is defined not in Presentation.Core , 
it kinda seems like your running on .net 2.0 press properties on your executable project and check what framework it targets

Answer (score 0):

While I accept that Visual Studio is occasionally wrong, when it tells me that I need to add a reference, I usually just add it. I tend not to question it, as it usually tells you why you need it as well. In your case, it says *The type 'System.Windows.Input.ICommand' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced*. It doesn't come much simpler than that.

Now regarding your question about where is `System.Windows`, a [quick online search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027194/how-to-add-system-windows-dll-to-visual-studio-2010-express) would have told you that it is in the `WindowsBase` dll.

Finally, why is your referenced assembly using the `System.Windows.Input` from the `WindowsBase` dll instead of the `PresentationCore` dll? Who knows... all you need to know is that it doesn't... it uses the one from the `WindowsBase` dl, so that is the one that you need to reference to fix your problem.

---

UPDATE >>>

If you are only using that MVVM Toolkit so that you can use the `RelayCommand` then you might as well create your own class based on (or even copied from) the original. You can find the original implementation of the `RelayCommand` in Josh Smith's [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090030) article on MSDN. That way, you won't need to reference that dll at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I referenced all dlls, still problem not solved. I moved to .NET 4.5 and still has same problem...

Comment: Whenever PresentationCore and System.Windows are referenced this error occur.  this only when I am using RelayCommand of MVVM Toolkit light

Comment: Ok, after upgrade to VS 2013 things were resolved. Thanks you all